# polars: compute row-wise quantile over DataFrame

Tags: python, python-polars

I have some polars DataFrames over which I want to compute some row-wise statistics.

For some there is a `.list.func` function which exists (eg [`list.mean`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.mean.html)), however, for those which don't have a dedicated function I believe I must use [`list.eval`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.eval.html).

For the following example data:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,10,1,.1,.1,     np.NAN],
    'b': [2, 8,1,.2, np.NAN,np.NAN],
    'c': [3, 6,2,.3,.2,     np.NAN],
    'd': [4, 4,3,.4, np.NAN,np.NAN],
    'e': [5, 2,3,.5,.3,     np.NAN],
})
```

I have managed to come up with the following expression.

It seems that `list.eval` returns a list (which I suppose is more generic) so I need to call `.explode` on the resulting 1-element list to get back a single value.

The resulting column takes the name of the first column, so I then need to call `.alias` to give it a more meaningful name.

```py
df.select(
    pl.concat_list(
        pl.all().fill_nan(None)
    )
    .list.eval(pl.element().quantile(0.25))
    .explode()
    .alias('q1')
)
```

Is this the recommended way of computing row-wise?

Comment: That is the workaround approach for non-existing horizontal/list functions. The plan is to have dedicated horizontal equivalents: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9966

Comment: @jqurious thanks for confirming! Do you know if there is any performance penalty using the "generic" `list.eval` vs the equivalent dedicated function (eg `list.mean`)? I need to compute a number of statistics which will all look very similar, am thinking I might create a wrapper function which just takes a `polars.Expr` and have all the rest of the boilerplate in one place

Comment: Yeah, there is a performance penalty (this is why they require separate implementations at the Rust level). If you use an example where a dedicated horizontal function exists e.g. `sum` you should be able to see a difference: `pl.sum_horizontal()` vs. `list.sum()` vs. `list.eval(pl.element().sum())`

Comment: To be expected I suppose! Thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would melt and join here. It should be faster than `.list.eval` plus it let's you more easily add other row wise aggregations. Note I've added q2,q3,q4 to the `agg`

```
(
    (_df:=df.with_row_index('i'))
    .join(
        _df
        .melt('i')
        .group_by('i')
        .agg(
            pl.col('value').quantile(x).alias(q)
            for q,x in {'q1':0.25,'q2':0.50, 'q3':0.75, 'q4':1}.items()
            ), 
        on='i'
        )
    .sort('i')
    .drop('i')
    )

shape: (6, 9)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬───┬─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   ┆ … ┆ q1  ┆ q2  ┆ q3  ┆ q4   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆   ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═══╪═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1.0  ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 4.0 ┆ … ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 4.0 ┆ 5.0  │
│ 10.0 ┆ 8.0 ┆ 6.0 ┆ 4.0 ┆ … ┆ 4.0 ┆ 6.0 ┆ 8.0 ┆ 10.0 │
│ 1.0  ┆ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ … ┆ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 3.0  │
│ 0.1  ┆ 0.2 ┆ 0.3 ┆ 0.4 ┆ … ┆ 0.2 ┆ 0.3 ┆ 0.4 ┆ 0.5  │
│ 0.1  ┆ NaN ┆ 0.2 ┆ NaN ┆ … ┆ 0.2 ┆ 0.3 ┆ NaN ┆ NaN  │
│ NaN  ┆ NaN ┆ NaN ┆ NaN ┆ … ┆ NaN ┆ NaN ┆ NaN ┆ NaN  │
└──────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴───┴─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘
```

I used the walrus operator to create `_df` so as to not have to invoke `.with_row_index` twice. If you prefer you can just do `df=df.with_row_index('i')` first instead.

Comment: Ha, that's cool! Thanks! Do you know why melt & join is faster than list.eval? I'm somewhat surprised they don't end up doing the same thing under the hood

Comment: Another question please, so you know if this performance gain is felt even when only aggregating to a single statistic?

Comment: To your first question, is [this](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7124#issuecomment-1451421346) which isn't much but it's a response from the main author. To your second question, I'm not sure but probably. I suppose it would depend on the data. I make concerted efforts not to use `.list.eval` for this reason so if it's improved then I probably wouldn't ever notice.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Not much to go on, but sufficient to convince me to switch to the join and melt approach!

Comment: I think that `.eval` warning may be outdated, it was reimplemented soon after so that it runs on the `group_by` engine instead: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/8199 @SteveLorimer As I understand it, when you create a List in Polars - data is copied - so the overhead mainly comes from `pl.concat_list(pl.all())` (not just `list.eval`)

Comment: @jqurious second that thanks. I didn't know they did that. Although I just reran that same comparison and the overall times are way down but, the list.eval  (replacing arr with list) method is still about 5x the time of the melt/group_by. I think your point about `concat_list` making copies is the source of the continued slowness.